# Weight Painting Mirroring Issue

Tags: weight-painting, mirror

I'm trying to weight paint my character. I have applied automatic weights and am touching up areas. In the Context section on the right side windows (not the 'N' window but the one to the right), there's an option for mirrored weight painting along the x-axis. Unfortunately when I toggle this, it paints both the left and right side for the selected bone. How can I paint weights for one bone so that it corresponds with the same bone opposite the x-axis?

TLDR: weight paint x-axis mirror paints correctly but connects it to original bone rather than corresponding opposite one.

Answer (score 2):

That mirror option is for a center bone that should control left and right side of a mesh at the same way (like a hip bone, a torso, and so on ...).

To have R side bone matching the L side (like arms or legs) this is one procedure:

Weight paint the L side (i.e. arm.L, the name of the vertex group must have an appropriate suffix, like .L or .l or .left).

Then select the option copy vertex group, then mirror vertex group, then rename appropriately (like arm.R).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Please mark the answer as "accepted" (up arrow).