# Can't mirror weight paint even with X mirror

Tags: weight-painting

I know there is an X mirror option, and I found it. But it doesn't work. My vertex groups have .L and .R at the end.
But X mirror seems to be switching of or doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer solve your problems? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163450/weight-painting-mirroring-issue/163460#163460

Comment: Yes it solves it. Thank you

Comment: If so, please give it an upvote, thank you.