# Mirror Weightpaint

Tags: weight-painting

I have this problem a lot and I haven't been able to fix it I can mirror the weight paint onto the opposite bone my Armature is Symmetrical and I have the suffix .R and .L but it doesn't work is it my blender version??
[image]

Comment: here is some other pics[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awjhz.jpg

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ek6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Mirror brush across the X axis" option at the top left of the 3D view.

[image]

Comment: Another way: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163450/weight-painting-mirroring-issue/163460#163460

Comment: all it did was paint the weight but dint attach it to the symmetrical bone